# A "native container"-"device management server" pair to push Html5 apps

Tags: html, server-push

We have multiple customers and each customer would have multiple apps. One more thing is that users would have different apps (workflow apps, chart apps, administration apps, etc.) assigned by their roles.

And these customers would prefer installing only a single native app and use it for all of their workflows. They want to manage who uses what.

These Html5 apps then would be updated automatically with the push, users don't need to do anything.

I am looking for a solution to make the following happen:

- Developer writes Html5 apps
- Developer sends the app (html, js, css, etc.) to the device manager / application manager (TOOL for short)
- TOOL pushes the apps to users' devices
- Within the TOOL, I should be able tell which users use which apps
- The native container (NC for short) receives the HTML5 apps from the TOOL
- Users select the app they want to run within NC from one of the assigned tools
- NC runs them in an embedded webview
- NC is providing some API for camera, etc (optional)

Does anyone know such solution? Any technical terms would also be helpful.

There is a tool from Sybase, "Hybrid Web container", however it seems it is only good for SAP-related things.

Answer (score 0):

As HTML5 becomes more widely used as a development standard for mobile applications, the issue of app containers that can be accessed and managed on a variety of mobile devices is going to become more and more important to enable BYOD or cross-platform mobile access at a realistic cost.

Azurati has been doing some interesting work in the area of HTML5 mobile app containers recently.  Have a look at:  http://www.azurati.com/products/azurati-mobile-portal/

This solution is slightly different to the 'native' container scenario that you outline above because Azurati's app container itself is also HTML5, but it does support authenticated user access based on roles, you can assign and manage apps to specific role groups and users can make use of HTML5 apps in offline mode and use device functions like location services, etc.